# My cat vomited and pooped in the house?

Tags: cats, feeding, diseases

My cat pooped on my bed last night and a few days ago my sister noticed he vomited on the floor. He's a little over a year and usually goes out in the garden to poop. We haven't changed the kind of food we give him, but up until now there was always someone home to give the cats food.

Now with school starting they get food at around 6 am and then again not until 3 pm; could it just be him reacting badly to the sudden change in the feeding schedule? Or that he ate too much too quickly? Could it point to something more serious? Up until now he hasn't been sick and he's acting pretty much like usual, maybe only a bit strange.

Comment: Did he poop in the house too? Your question title indicates it but you didn't mention it in the text.

Comment: do your cat have a catflap so he can get out when he needs to?.

Comment: Oh, I meant that he pooped on my bed last night, but I wrote wrong word. And before that he vomited in the house. He doesn't have a catflap, but he goes to the balcony door and scratches lightly the blinds (we have glass doors) so we know when to let him out. Up until now that has never been the problem for him, even if it's the middle of the night.

Comment: When you say, "he's acting pretty much like usual, maybe only a bit strange"; do you mean the pooping on bed and vomit is strange OR that there are other behaviors that are strange too? If other strange behaviors, what kind do you mean? Or what else have you observed? Please note how many other cats you have, how they usually act together, ages and if all kitties are spayed/neutered. :)

Answer (score 3):

If he does it anymore, take him to the vet. If he goes outside, he could have easily eaten something toxic (or done so in your house), or contracted something from another cat. There are all kinds of diseases cats can get from other cats.

ie. distemper:
http://wavy.com/2017/09/05/50-cats-dead-after-virus-spreads-through-shelter/

If you want what's best for your cat, you really should keep it outdoors 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

Cats can be crazy sometimes.  We had a cat that would get upset with someone for some reason like being out too late or staying away too long.  The cat would get under the bed covers and poop.  Leaving a little surprise for its person.  It only did it once guess it was satisfied with the statement.